# Do developers use internet to check for code syntax or to remind themselves about some code while on work

Tags: syntax

I am not sure if StackOverflow is the right forum to ask this question. If I am wrong, please point me to the right forum.

I am still junior android developer, and I always wondered about one question.

Do software developers sometimes use internet to check for code syntax or to check for some code for some action, that they never used before, or didn't use for a long time, and simply need to remind themselves about that code?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that they *wouldn't*?

Comment: This is the right place to do so! I am programming many languages so im always browsing for syntax. The goal is not to copy some code. The goal is to use some exemple to acheive your own!

Comment: Nope. I wanted to be sure if that is okay to remind yourself on internet about some code while on work, or do employers expect from you to know everything you may need to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the personalty of the developer, I for one had a time in my life when i was **code happy** and all I try to do then is solve my own problem myself thereby impressing my fellow developers and peers, in return I wasted time doing one simple thing for days and time is money.

But as it is now, money must be made and more money to be made means more jobs to be done for clients.

If I have a whole lot of issues on my mind e.g the flow process of the application, the limited time frame to deliver, another job from a pestering client (who paid higher than the current client), personal problems, etc. The least thing I want to do is to disturb my head about some code I know but cant remember. **I look it up in no time**.

Yes, I look up a lot of codes i don't remember and wish not to remember and no one cares because at the end of the day it is the developer that get his/her job done at the specified time that is a good developer.

You will find out that as you grow in your career if you work as a freelance programmer, except in limited cases, NO CLIENT will tell you write a sample code to do bla bla bla.

What they care about is the manner in which you solve the problem they have. Your problem solving logic is what makes you a better programmer every single day.

It doesn't mean you should forget all your code but don't stress over it if you don't remember look it up, it doesn't cause a volcanic eruption in central park...lolz.

**BUT** you must also remember that if you make it an habit to always look up your code, in no time you will have issues reading codes and that is a crime as a computer programmer.

My advise for you as a

> junior android developer

is that you learn to disconnect from the internet most times when you write your codes it will strengthen your brain to remember your codes better. Because what i have found out over time is that there are two types of programmers,

1. offline
2. online

The offline programmer would survive even in the desert but the Online programmer can only survive in the city.

Lastly if you were a client and you called two programmers to add extra page to an android application. Then you looked at their various systems and one of the was editing his code while the other was on google or other site like stack overflow with page title

> How to add extra page to android application?

Be sincere with yourself who will you rather work with next time?

Don't get it wrong there is no crime in asking but sometimes asking is the last thing you want to do because its more shameful that stealing.

Wish you luck in your career path...trust me with consistency you will exceed your peers because you have chosen the extra ordinary careea path.

Answer (score 1):

We use it for anything.

Don't know how to do something at all?
*Ask the internet.*

Know how, but forget what the function name is?
*Ask the internet.*

Remember the name, but forget the order of parameters?
Sing it with me: *Ask the internet!*

There are no rules about when it's OK and when it's not. Use it when it helps.